# convert a txt file into numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, text

I have a large txt file and I extracted part of it by the following code:
My extracted data has the following structure and I want to store each column including numbers as a separate vector for doing some modifications. I would be really thankful if someone could tell me how can I do this.

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
code:

coordinate=[]
with open('logfile.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line[0:2]=="Pt":
            coordinate.append(line)
coordinate = [x.strip() for x in coordinate]
coordinate_new=np.array(coordinate)
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
extracted data:

Pt      13.85929291      -8.31557575     -13.72000000
Pt      13.85929291      -5.54371716     -13.72000000
Pt      13.85929291      -2.77185858     -13.72000000
Pt      13.85929291      -0.00000000     -13.72000000
Pt      13.85929291       2.77185858     -13.72000000
Pt      13.85929291       5.54371716     -13.72000000
Pt      13.85929291       8.31557575     -13.72000000
Pt      13.85929291      11.08743433     -13.72000000
Pt     -12.47336362     -12.47336362       0.00000000
Pt     -12.47336362      -9.70150504       0.00000000
Pt     -12.47336362      -6.92964646       0.00000000
Pt     -12.47336362      -4.15778787       0.00000000
Pt     -12.47336362      -1.38592929       0.00000000
Pt     -12.47336362       1.38592929       0.00000000
Pt     -12.47336362       4.15778787       0.00000000
Pt     -12.47336362       6.92964646       0.00000000
Pt     -12.47336362       9.70150504       0.00000000
Pt     -12.47336362      12.47336362       0.00000000
Pt      -9.70150504     -12.47336362       0.00000000
Pt      -9.70150504      -9.70150504       0.00000000
Pt      -9.70150504      -6.92964646       0.00000000

```````````````````````````````
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Do you want to read the file and store column 1, column2, and column3 as three `numpy` arrays?

Comment: Have you considered csv.reader()? Depending on the text file format, it could simplify both reading the data AND structuring into Numpy arrays.

Comment: @sentence yes, that is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be one of the hack to solve your problem,

```
lists = []
lst_not_append = True

with open('logfile.txt','r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    no = len(lines[0].split())
    if lst_not_append:
        for i in range(no):
            lists.append([])

    for line in lines:
        for i, l in enumerate(line.split()):
            lists[i].append(l)

    arrs = np.array(lists)
```

Note: `arrs` is `2d` array and each of its element will represent a column of your `text file`. Here, `arrs[0]` represents `first column` of text file, `arrs[1]` represents `second column` of text file and so on. This solution is generic and it will cope up with every text file whatever the no. of columns it have.

Comment: @Shahin Mohamadnejad let me know if this worked for you ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The thing is my original text file (logfile.txt) doesn't have just 4 columns. It is a large file and each part of it has different numbers of rows and columns. As I mentioned I extracted these four columns which I am interested in, and I want to store each of the three last columns as an array.

Comment: @ShahinMohamadnejad in above answer, I did the same what you are requiring. Am I right ?

Comment: It doesn't do what I want. The thing is you are assuming that the whole of my txt file has four columns and this assumption is not correct. The four columns that I put here is just part of my txt file which I am interested in. Generally, each part of my txt file has a different number of columns.

Comment: so whatever the no. of columns in your text file, you want a numpy array for each column. For example, if a file has 20 columns, then there will be 20 numpy arrays. Right ?

Comment: what do you mean by part of text file ?

Comment: the number of columns in each part of my text file is different. So I cannot divide the whole file by a fixed number of columns.

Comment: Here is an example of two rows in my file                                                                  Pt      13.85929291     -11.08743433     -13.72000000                                         VEC1      27.71858582       0.00000000       0.00000000      2.77185858

Comment: SO it means each `numpy array` size will be different because of missing values as you mentioned first two rows ?

Comment: @ShahinMohamadnejad I have understand your point but I need your text file otherwise it's not possible to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html?highlight=loadtxt):

```
import numpy as np

c1,c2,c3 = np.loadtxt('logfile.txt', usecols=(1, 2, 3), unpack=True)
```